# How to replace commas by semicolon but not inside quotes

Tags: python, bash, csv, groovy, replace

I have something like the following CSV:

```
"blah blah, foo bar", 1, 454, ok, eng
blah blah foo bar, 2, 21, ko, esp
...
```

I need to replace the commas between fields into semicolons so I can split correctly the CSV. But don't the ones inside the quoutes.

I need or a regex o a little script(python, groovy, bash...) to fix this.

Comment: Do you need solution in `bash` or `python`?

Comment: Agreed with tim_yates. This is an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341): you say you want to change commas to semicolons, but what you really want to do is parse a CSV file, and you are trying to change the commas to semicolons as part of doing this. You should instead use Python's `csv` module. Still, props for putting the CSV bit into your question! Otherwise we'd have just told you how to do the substitution and you'd still be wasting your time reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using Python's `csv` module. Demo:

```
from csv import reader, writer
with open('input.csv') as inp, open('output.csv', 'w') as out:
    writer(out, delimiter=';').writerows(reader(inp))
```

file contents:

```
$ cat input.csv 
"blah blah, foo bar", 1, 454, ok, eng
blah blah foo bar, 2, 21, ko, esp
$ cat output.csv 
blah blah, foo bar; 1; 454; ok; eng
blah blah foo bar; 2; 21; ko; esp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

infile = open("inputfile.csv", "r")
outfile = open("outputfile.csv", "w")

csvReader = csv.reader(infile)

for line in csvReader:
    outfile.write(";".join(line) + "\n")

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Tested on Python 2.7 and 3.5

Output on your example:

```
blah blah, foo bar; 1; 454; ok; eng
blah blah foo bar; 2; 21; ko; esp
```